# Qt and manual input events

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to process manually created input event like this:

```
 class WebView : public QWebView {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
 ...
     Q_INVOKABLE bool ProcessEvent(QEvent *ev) {
         bool res = this->event(ev);
         delete ev;
         return res;
     }
 ...
 };
```

And send it from another thread like this:

```
QEvent *ev = new QMouseEvent{ QEvent::MouseMove, { msg->x, msg->y }, Qt::NoButton, Qt::NoButton, Qt::NoModifier };
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(web_view_, "ProcessEvent", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QEvent *, ev));
```

It works fine on windows, but on linux (Ubuntu) after a few dozens of events i get a crash with an error:

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
web_daemon: ../../src/xcb_io.c:165: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq` failed.
```

I use Qt::QueuedConnection, so method will be called from GUI thread and i should not get any threading problems.
I use manually compiled, statically linked Qt 4.8.7, but i guess i do something fundamentally wrong here, so version does not matter.

Comment: Based on the `libxcb` messages you might want to try [`QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_X11InitThreads)`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum)

Comment: That actually helped! Seems like construction of QMouseEvent itself from another thread was a problem and setting that attribute solved it.